# Django DB Excludes using multilpe Values

Tags: django

Does anyone know how I can use multiple values within the db exclude filter in Django.

```
Event.objects.filter(task="123").exclude(user=["bob","fred"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you'd use it in `filter`: with `__in`:

```
Event.objects.filter(task="123").exclude(user__in=["bob","fred"])
```